# Drotek - GPSD and NTRIP Correction data for precise positioning

Tags: localization, gps, positioning, gpsd

I need centimeter precision using a GPS Antenna and a Drotek - ZED-F9P board.
The board is connected via its usb interface to a linux machine.
And with gpsd installed and the command cgps -s one can see the latitude and longitude but it varies by a lot due to the missing correction data.
The question is, how would one implement a NTRIP Client to read the correction data (in my case from SAPOS) and input it into gpsd.
As far is I know gpsd doesnt support that out of the box.

I already tried to use rtklib -> rtkrcv / navi but couldnt really get the first one to work.
With the first one, I couldnt really find documentation on how to setup the conf file and for the latter, it could connect to the SAPOS NTRIP caster but couldnt find the antenna / board. Or well it could, but it just wouldnt display any data (lat, lon, alt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the ntrip caster url as argument like so `ntrip://foo:bar@ntrip.example.com:80/example-stream`, as mentioned in manual. You can also add it to `GPSD_OPTIONS=""` field in /etc/default/gpsd configuration file. Then you will need to restart `gpsd` service like `sudo systemctl restart gpsd.service`.

Comment: How did i overlook this, wow... alrightie, ill try that aswell, my implementation works just fine but im having connection problems sometimes, like it would take up to 10 seconds to connect correctly to the ntrip caster and receive the correction data. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried it, works very well! Thank you! I have to implement a better interface though, not the python gpsd module, missing some status info. But ill get that working. Thanks mate!

Comment: I'm happy it worked for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got it working by implementing everything on my own, ntrip client aswell as the serial communication with the DROTEK board.
Sometimes the connection to the NTRIP service is lost, but it works just fine.
But even better with GPSD and ntrip, see answer above.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).